# Ticks not aligned with the cell in matplotlib table

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, heatmap

I am using matplotlib table to create a heatmap that contains different values. While creating the table, ticks are not aligned at the center of each cell in both x-axis and y-axis.
I want to create something like this.
[image]

But rather I am getting ticks that are not uniform in both axes. Ticks starts at the middle of the cell from bottom-left column and gets distorted while moving to top and right cell.
[image]

I am using this code to generate this matplotlip table.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap
import os
import sys
from matplotlib.table import Table


fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
tb = Table(ax,bbox=[0,0,1,1])

nrows, ncols = 20,20
width, height = 1.0 / ncols, 1.0 / nrows
headers = 20

data  = np.zeros((nrows, ncols))

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0.5,headers+0.5))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0.5,headers+0.5))
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=12)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=12)
    

for (i,j),val in np.ndenumerate(data):
    tb.add_cell(i, j, width, height)
    tb.add_cell(i, j, width, height, loc='center')

tb.auto_set_font_size(False)
tb.set_fontsize(15)
ax.add_table(tb)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Is there any particular reason to draw a heatmap with `matplotlib.table`? You can use `maptplotlib.pcolor` to realize a heat map.

Comment: The reason for using Matplotlib table is that it needs to display RGB color for each cell according to RGB values(R,G,B). RGB values will be pre-calculated and will be in form 255,255,255. I have already implemented RGB color display in each cell but got stucked in aligning the ticks in both axes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will do the work

```
plt.ylim(0,headers)
plt.xlim(0,headers)
```

also adding this line `plt.xticks(rotation=90)` will help you rotate values in the xaxis and avoid overlapping
full program will be like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap
import os
import sys
from matplotlib.table import Table

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))#
tb = Table(ax, bbox=[0, 0, 1, 1])

nrows, ncols = 20,20
width, height = 1.0 / ncols, 1.0 / nrows
headers = 20

data = np.zeros((nrows, ncols))

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0.5,headers+0.5))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0.5,headers+0.5))
plt.ylim(0,headers)
plt.xlim(0,headers)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=12)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=12)

for (i, j), val in np.ndenumerate(data):
    tb.add_cell(i, j, width, height)
    tb.add_cell(i, j, width, height, loc='center')

tb.auto_set_font_size(False)
tb.set_fontsize(15)
ax.add_table(tb)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: add `plt.xicks(rotation=90)` for rotating the values in xaxis

Comment: I have already implemented rotation. This alignment was the only thing I was stuck to. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of seaborn? This is a plotting library built on top of matplotlib that takes care of those things for you. They have a function `heatmap` which does exactly this, and handles the placing of the ticks automatically: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html#seaborn.heatmap

Example:

```
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.heatmap(np.zeros(20,20))
plt.show()
```

gives this:
[image]

You can then play with the ticklabels and modify them at will like you would do on any matplotlib plot. For example, `ax.set_xticklabels(np.arange(0.5, 20, 0.5))` will rename your x-ticks like on your picture.

Comment: I have to use matplotlib table to display RGB color values calculated for each cell. Though ticks align well in simple heatmap using Matplotlib, it is acting somewhat strange after using table.

Answer (score 0):

The answers have been accepted through a lot of trial and error, but we're changing the idea and color mapping. How about customizing it and using a heat map to solve the problem? It would be convenient to process various things. I will share it with you for your reference.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

mat = np.random.rand(10,10)

# RGB -> Hex
# ['rgb(0,0,205)', 'rgb(50,205,50)', 'rgb(255,69,0)'] -> ['#0000cd', '#32cd32', '#ff4500']
# ['mediumblue', 'limegreen', 'orangered'])
rgb_c = [(0,0,205), (50,205,50), (255,69,0)]
# RGB convert to Hex
cols = ['#%02x%02x%02x' % (c[0],c[1],c[2]) for c in rgb_c]

cm = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(cols)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
heatmap = ax.pcolor(mat, cmap=cm)

ax.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```

[image]